# Javascript dataTable design jquery

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have problems with dataTable border bottom. I wanna to delete that border line. And how I can put background image on tr in dataTable? Can someone help with this?  Here is picture [image: Problem]

And here is code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
    <div class="mini-submenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
        <span href="#" class="list-group-item active" style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', monospace; font-size: 15px; background-color: #2b669a">
            Places near you
            <span class="pull-right" id="slide-submenu">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
        <table id="myTable1" class="table table-row-cell" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-bottom: none">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="naslov col-sx-7" style="background-image: none; background-color: white; color : #0a68b4">Place</th>
                    <th class="naslov" style="background-image: none; background-color: white; color : #0a68b4">Distance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for(place <- places) {
                    <tr onclick="window.location='@routes.PlaceController.viewPlace(place.id)'" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <td class="naslov">@place.title</td>
                        <td id="distance-nearby-places-@place.id" class="naslov"></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and script

```
<script>
    var table;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function drawTable() {
            table = $('#myTable1').DataTable({
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                bFilter: false,
                bInfo: false,
                bPaginate: false,
                sScrollY: 300
            });
        };
        function calculateDistances() {
            var mapCenter;
            var index = 0;
            var counter = 0;
            @for(place <- places){
@if(place.latitude != null || place.longitude != null){
                    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(@place.latitude, @place.longitude);
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                            var pos = {
                                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                lng: position.coords.longitude
                            };
                            mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
                            var distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(mapCenter, new google.maps.LatLng(@place.latitude, @place.longitude)) / 1000).toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('distance-nearby-places-@place.id').innerText = distance + " km";
                            index++;
                            counter++;
                            if(counter == @places.size()) {
                                drawTable();
                            }
                        }, function() {
                            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                         handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                    }
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('distance-nearby-places-@place.id').innerText = "n/a";
                    counter++;
                }
}
        }
        calculateDistances();
        //setTimeout(drawTable, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`scrollCollapse: true`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollCollapse) option to reduce table in height when limited number of rows are shown.

Comment: Thanks. Do u know how to add background image ?